# Change css from data-number

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If this is a poor question I apologize in advance, I'll try to make it as clear as possible.

I'm making a game from jquery + HTML 5. It's a round based game, if you win a round the round number increases by 1, if you lose, the round number resets to 0. Example:

```
    endGame: function() {
        $($('[data-round]').get(0)).text('0');
```

This all works perfectly fine, What I need is to change a CSS element based off of `$('[data-round]'`). for every time the number increases I need a CSS element to increase in height by 20px.

Specifically:

I need to increase `#fill{ height: 0px;}` +20px. every time `$('[data-round]')` increases by 1. Then if `$('[data-round]')` returns to 0, `#fill{ height: 0px;}`

so..

```
if ('[data-round]') = 0 then #fill{ height: 0px;}

and ('[data-round]') = 1 then #fill{ height: 20px;}

('[data-round]') = 2 then #fill{ height: 40px;}

('[data-round]') = 3 then #fill{ height: 60px;}
```

and so on.. Can anybody help?

HTML structure:

```
<h2 id="rnd" style="display: none;">Round: <span style="color:red;"  data-round="0">0</span></h2>
                <button id="pgb" class="btn1" onclick="showDiv()" data-action="start" >Play Game</button><br>
                <p style="display: none;" data-action="lose">Sorry, you lost after <span style="color:red; font-weight: bold;" data-round="0"></span> rounds!</p>
```

Comment: write down your dom structure

Comment: post your html code..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#fill').css({
    height: parseInt($('[data-round]').data('round')) * 20 + 'px' 
});
```

not sure what value your `$('[data-round]')` will return though, as you haven't shown the markup here.

Comment: @Mr_Green i do not know what his html looks like.

Comment: Yes, but you are multiplying `20` with a jquery object. which will result in `NaN`.

Comment: No need parseInt in this context data automatically taken the number is integer

Comment: Tried this,doesn't seem to change the CSS element at all. Also added HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a variable to store the fillHeight value. then run an if statement to see if the data-round is grater than 0. If so add 20 to the fillHeight var otherwise reset the fillHeight to 0.

```
var fillHeight = 0;

if('[data-round]' > 0){
    fillHeight + 20;
} else {
    fillHeight = 0;
}

$('#fill').css({'height': fillHeight+'px'});
```

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work, even with a stripped down version which just increases data-round onclick.